# Laravel 5 can't capture form input

Tags: forms, laravel, input

**EDIT** I am not using resource controller but I believe my route is correct

I have a form on it called `recordings` I have the form like:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/recordings/create') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Client Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {!! Form::select('ClientName', $client_options, '', array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">File</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="FileUpload">
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Submit
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then in my `RecordingsController`

```
public function store()
{
  var_dump(Input::file('FileUpload'));  
  var_dump(Input::get('ClientName')) ;
 }
```

My route:

```
Route::get('recordings/create', 'RecordingsController@create');
Route::post('recordings/create', 'RecordingsController@store');
```

Why is it the `var_dump` is null? I have a dropdown which has values in it and I already selected one. The other one is file input filed which I also selected already a file.

Comment: Strange, but your form action is 'recordings/create', is this mapped to RecordingsController@store? If you are using resource controllers, you should use url('recordings') for form action, with post method.

Comment: @Iamzozo sorry my mistake. Not resource controller but my route is properly set I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $ClientName = $request->ClientName:        

    if ($this->request->hasFile('FileUpload'))
    {
        $files = $this->request->file('FileUpload');
        ....
```

Or simple use

```
dd($request);
```

Always a good idea here is to use Firebug - to check out which values are submitted to your script.

Comment: Tried it the result is just Request {#199} or object(Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request)[199] in var_dump

Comment: Ok so youre receiving an empty request here. There are now multiple ways to find out what happened. The best idea would be to use Firebug (Firefox extension) to see your requests in detail. Other idea is to check which an HttpRequester manually your store method (you are able to send Post values to any route/script) - Ohter idea is: Try to disbale multipart/formdata to check out if any values are sendet to your Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Works now. Problem is I am sending huge data in my post. So I did is changed the `post_max_size` in my php.ini. Weird though I am not getting error regarding that.